# The number of strings that contain any characters that are not alphabetic characters

Tags: python, list

I am a few weeks into learning python properly and couldn't find a way to proceed from what I currently have. The question is:

> Use the accumulator pattern to write a function count_messy(strings) that takes a list of strings as a parameter and returns an int representing the number of strings that contain any characters that are not alphabetic characters. The string method isalpha will be useful here.

Here's my current code:

```
def count_messy(strings):
    for string in strings:
        ans = strings.isalpha(string)
        
    return(len(ans))

print(count_messy(["x", "y2y", "zz%z"]))
```

Should output:

```
2
```

Preferably the use of `for` loops for the accumulator pattern and no list comprehension will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is *your* question?

Comment: The accumulator pattern (had to look it up...) does not need to build a list, but merely *count* things. Do you know how to count, e.g. increase a variable by ``1``?

Comment: Your program should have a variable that is a number and 1 is added to it each time a string with a non-alphabetic character is found.

Comment: The accumlator pattern we were taught is like ( for num in strings (next line) result += num) etc which just stores the code for next loop I think. The question is basically return the number of characters that does not have alphabetical characters. The test is print(count_messy(["x", "y2y", "zz%z"]))

Comment: Your code uses ``=``, not ``+=`` as you note for the accumulator pattern. Is that intentional?

Comment: i did try using += however couldn't get a close answer

Comment: @penguins1234 - re read my notes in the re-edit. I linked the api for str you had many things wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to end this...

The correct solution is:

```
def count_messy(strings):
    count = 0
    for string in strings:
        if not string.isalpha():
            count += 1
    return count
```

Issues with the original code and with several other solution attempts included:

- `isalpha` is a method of the string `string`, not of the list `strings`.
- `not string.isalpha()` must be used to count the strings that do *not* consist only of alphabetic characters.
- A `count` integer variable needs to be initialized with 0 and incremented for each string fulfilling this condition.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I appreciate your persistence haha I would upvote if I could